# How do I reset a collection in Titanium Alloy?

Tags: jasmine, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

A Backbonejs collection has a function to [reset a collection](http://docs.appcelerator.com/backbone/0.9.2/#Collection-reset) for bulk updates. I would like to use this feature in Titanium Alloy when I sync with JSON data from a server but it appears as if this is not being committed/saved to SQLite - I am using an sql adapter.

```
config: {
        columns: {
            // stuff
            name: "TEXT"
        },
        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "pony",
            db_name: Alloy.CFG.db_name
        }
    }
```

I have some jasmine tests which keep failing. FYI I have migration script for development that adds 7 items to the collection so that I have something to work with.

```
describe("pony model", function () {
    var Alloy = require("alloy")
            data = {name: "My little pony"},
        collection,
        item;

    beforeEach(function(){
        collection = Alloy.createCollection('pony');
        item = Alloy.createModel('pony');
    });

    // PASSES
    it('can reset all data', function () {
        collection.fetch();
        expect(collection.length).toEqual(7);

        collection.reset(data)
        expect(collection.length).toEqual(1);
     })

     // FAILS
     it('saves reset data', function () {
        collection.fetch();
        expect(collection.length).toEqual(7);

        collection.reset(data)
        collection.fetch()
        expect(collection.length).toEqual(1);
     })

     afterEach(function () {
         item.destroy();
     });
})
```

The way this bug shows in the UI is that when I save that when I sync data with the server the TableView shows the new records then when I go to another view and come back to the same TableView the synced data is gone and replaced with the default data.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: No I didn't - I stopped trying.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach I found (and I shamefully can't remember where I copied the code from) was to do the reset manually. I posted the code to do this: https://gist.github.com/sukima/8321859

Basically I do my own SQL `DELETE` then a Backbone `reset()`, then looped `INSERT INTO`, finally finishing with a backbone `trigger("fetch")` event. Doing this via backbone's sync was way to slow. And the normal `reset()` doesn't run sync anyways.

```
exports.definition = {

  config: {
    columns: {
      // ...
    },
    adapter: {
      type:            "sql",
      collection_name: "MyModels"
    }
  },

  extendCollection: function(Collection) {

    Collection.prototype.destroyAll = function(opt) {
      var db = Ti.Database.open(this.config.adapter.db_name);
      db.execute("DELETE FROM " + this.config.adapter.collection_name);
      db.close();
      this.models = [];
      if (!opt || !opt.silent) { this.trigger("reset"); }
      return this;
    };

    Collection.prototype.saveAll = function(opt) {
      var util    = require("alloy/sync/util");
      var dbName  = this.config.adapter.db_name;
      var table   = this.config.adapter.collection_name;
      var columns = this.config.columns;
      var db      = Ti.Database.open(dbName);

      db.execute("BEGIN;");

      this.forEach(function (model) {
        if (!model.id) {
          model.id = util.guid();
          model.attributes[model.idAttribute ] = model.id;
        }
        var names = [], values = [], q = [];
        for (var k in columns) {
          names.push(k);
          values.push(model.get(k));
          q.push("?");
        }
        var sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + names.join(",") + ") VALUES (" + q.join(",") + ");";

        db.execute(sqlInsert, values);
      });

      db.execute("COMMIT;");
      db.close();

      if (!opt || !opt.silent) { this.trigger("reset"); }
      return this;
    };

    Collection.prototype.refreshFromData = function refreshFromData(data) {
      this.destroyAll({silent:true});
      this.reset(data, {silent:true});
      this.saveAll({silent: true});
      this.trigger("fetch");
    };

  }

};
```

Comment: This breaks on Alloy > 1.3 because the new alloy doesn't include the `alloy/sync/util.js` module. I can't figure out why. :'(

Comment: so what is the other alternative if alloy/sync/util.js module fails? Using an external db file is the only way out?

Comment: @anish, I have no idea, hence the "I can't figure out why" comment. I was foolishly hoping someone smarter than I would be willing to enlighten the rest of us.

Comment: The content of `util.js` is :  `function S4() {
    return (0 | 65536 * (1 + Math.random())).toString(16).substring(1);
}
 
exports.guid = function() {
    return S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4();
};` so can copy the above code in our module.